# How to rename a content type programmatically

Tags: 7, nodes

There are many answers and tutorials addressing the problem of changing the machine name of a content type, or migrating content types. However, I would like to rename a content type, without changing the machine name. This is what I tried:

```
$type = node_type_load('my_content_type');
$type->name = 'A new name';
node_type_save($type);
```

But this has no effect. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I assume editing it in the admin is not sufficient (perhaps for deployment purposes?)

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a D7 site, replaced `my_content_type` with `page`, and executed it...the name of the `page` node type was renamed to _A new name_ as expected. How are you checking to see if the changes took effect?

Comment: Based on @Clive's comment, looks like your code is not running.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it's for deployment.

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm quite sure it's running. Maybe I should add that this is a content type defined by a module, and not created through the UI. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Looking back on this after a year, I can't reproduce my own problem. This code works, even for content types defined by modules, not created through the UI:

```
$type = node_type_load('my_content_type');
$type->name = 'A new name';
node_type_save($type);
```